# FxCop rule for string ==?

Tags: string, fxcop, rule

Can anyone point me to an fxcop rule for identifing "string ==" usage. For example:

```
string s = "abc";
if (s == "def") {
    // do somethign
}
```

I want the "if" statement raised as an error. Roughly speaking I want to always be using string.compare with the appropriate culture.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to write your own custom rule for this, but it shouldn't be too hard. Refer to the files found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CustomFxCop/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1299). Also, use [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) to look at the FxCop libraries and get an idea of how this is done.